# Python Tabulate: Multiple Lists into Single Table

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use the `tabulate` package to print some tables. For example, I currently have a script that can take in a model run output log file and print some timings:

```
(437) $ ./GCM_Times_Tables.py -f 1day.works4.out  -t 1day --brief
GridComp          1day
-------------  -------
SUPERDYNAMICS   87.798
PHYSICS        246.729
AGCM           326.930
OGCM             1.879
GCS            330.248
HIST             9.229
EXTDATA         60.872

(438) $ ./GCM_Times_Tables.py -f 2day.out -t 2day --brief
GridComp          2day
-------------  -------
SUPERDYNAMICS  171.870
PHYSICS        484.011
AGCM           635.895
OGCM             2.454
GCS            640.896
HIST            17.739
EXTDATA        103.484
```

My script traverses the file and I end up with an OrderedDict:

```
OrderedDict([('SUPERDYNAMICS', 87.798), ('PHYSICS', 246.729), ('AGCM', 326.93), ('OGCM', 1.879), ('GCS', 330.248), ('HIST', 9.229), ('EXTDATA', 60.872)])
```

that I then parse through `tabulate`:

```
 print tabulate(myTimes.items(),headers=['GridComp',tag],tablefmt=tableFormat,floatfmt=".3f")
```

What I'd like to do now, though, is extend my script so that I can pass in multiple files (I do know how to do this in `argparse`) and then get something like:

```
GridComp          1day     2day
-------------  -------  -------
SUPERDYNAMICS   87.798  171.870 
PHYSICS        246.729  484.011
AGCM           326.930  635.895
OGCM             1.879    2.454
GCS            330.248  640.896
HIST             9.229   17.739
EXTDATA         60.872  103.484
```

which I can then run with "wikitable" format and paste into a wiki page.

I can easily pass in multiple files and I can easily extend my script to construct OrderedDicts for each file. Indeed, I can make an OrderedDict of OrderedDicts where the key on the "big" dictionary is the file name.

But, I cannot figure out what I'd need to do to get tabulate to like the results. Looking at the tabulate examples I've seen, I figure something where `combinedDict.items()` leads to:

```
[('SUPERDYNAMICS',87.798,171.870),('PHYSICS',246.729,484.011)...]
```

would be sufficient. What I can't seem to do is take those two OrderedDicts and "merge" them in this way. Is there a way to do this? Or maybe construct a list of lists:

```
[['SUPERDYNAMICS',87.798,171.870],['PHYSICS',246.729,484.011]...]
```

Comment: Some thing like [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), probably.  `itertools.chain.from_iterable([dict1.items(), dict2.items(), dict3.items()])`